# Extending argv to hold more values

Tags: c++, c

This is mostly out of curiosity.

In the ISO C specification the following is said:

> The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall
>   be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
>   startup and program termination.

http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1425.pdf section 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

Still, I have seen recommendations online that you shouldn't reallocate argv to extend it, but rather copy it.

Is there a specific reason to not extend argv that doesn't affect other char** or is this by convention?

I don't know if there is any real need for extending argv with additional values, but the question is whether argv is special from the POV of the program.

Comment: Well, to start with, you don't know how `argv` was allocated, if it were allocated at all...

Comment: And if it *was* `malloced` in the normal way, the library that's calling `main()` may try and `free` it afterwards, resulting in a double-free. You can mess with the contents, but you don't own the object.

Comment: What do you mean by "reallocate"? You certainly can't use `realloc` since it (almost certainly) didn't come from `malloc` (and even if it did, the runtime would probably want to `free` it when the program exits). You'd need to allocate some new memory and copy the `argv` pointers into that.

Comment: While argv can be modified and the language certainly allows it, from a design/maintenance perspective it's far easier if you treat it as const. Its just an array of char*s and not special.

Comment: I'd say the same works extending the vectors: [Extract some command line args before passing remainder to legacy code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821800/extract-some-command-line-args-before-passing-remainder-to-legacy-code/24822073#24822073)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I didn't consider the caller's side of it. It makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing special about argc and argv as parameters.

1) argc is just an int that is passed by copy into the main function. changing it has
absolutely no affect on anything.

2) argv, is just an array of pointers to c-strings. The standard lets you modify the strings pointed to by argv.

Note that the standard does not let you free the strings pointed to by argv nor does it
say you are allowed to modify the array pointed to by argv.

For example, if argc==2 and argv[1] points to a string "hello world", this would be fine:

```
argv[1][0]='c'; // the string is now "cello world" which is the name of a store
                // located right next to banjo emporium.
```

but it is undefined to do:

```
argv[1] = "yo mamma"; // what are you thinking, are you 12 ???
```

Although, nothing bad happens if you do that -- it is just not defined. A test on centos 6.5 with gcc 4.4 (Don't make fun of me for using such an old version, okay?) gave me no
issues. So nobody is trying to free() the contents of argv on program exit. Also there are several libraries that as a side effect of processing argv, reorder
its contents. I cannot think of where I saw that though.

However, what you cannot do, because you have no way to do it, is to change the size of
the array pointed to by argv. For example, on my system, trying to realloc() argv throws an invalid pointer error. In other words, the array pointed to by argv, does not appear to be located on the heap.

Not being able to realloc() arrays passed into your functions is nothing new or special, for example the array might be static, or allocated on the stack, and the standard says nothing about how the argv array is allocated.

In any case, the standard allows the programmer to use the strings passed into main in any way without fear that they will be modified by somebody else, but it does not explicitly let the programmer change the array that holds the strings.

Comment: _So nobody is trying to free() the contents of argv on program exit_ which, why bother? All of your memory is being reclaimed by the OS at exit anyway.

Comment: Suspect `argv = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));` is OK. and then `argv` can be `realloc()`.  `argv` can be changed, but not the array it originally pointed to.

Comment: @chux I printed out the argv pointer, and took a look at the memory map of the application -- on Centos6.5, with gcc4.4, argv was pointing to memory reserved for the stack. Further investigation showed that it was only 33 bytes away from another variable declared on the stack. edit: oh nevermind, I see what you are saying.

Comment: @OfNothing The last comments confused me a bit. Would this be correct: argv points to some piece of memory which we don't know where is, or how large it is, but we can make argv point to a new section of memory that we control. The caller of our program will then not be able to free the original memory if desired, but exiting the program would free it anyway. So in practice it doesn't matter? Is this different on different OSes?

Comment: @codeponderer You are almost correct. You have the setup right, argv points to memory that is out of the programmers control. Also, it would be perfectly legal to make argv point to memory in our control. However, the variable argv is just a copy of a pointer to that memory because when an array is passed to a function it is just actually passing a copy of a pointer to the first element of the array. The calling function may still have its own copy of that pointer as well. Modifying main()'s copy of argv won't modify the caller's copy of argv, and so the caller would still have access to it.

Comment: @codeponderer But it is true that if an element of argv is replaced with a different string, the caller might loose the reference to it. Replacing an element in linux or windows works without a problem, but I can imagine that might not be universal.

Comment: @RobK If for example your C program was compiled into a simple uni-kernel implementation where "reclaimed by the OS" turns into one or more calls to a function like `free`. Or you're on minimal hardware with no memory management unit and the OS is also relying on just hitting pointers with a `free`-like function (obviously this is very insecure in the face of untrusted or incorrect code, but in some embedded contexts you might argue your minimal OS doesn't need to worry about that). Contrived, but it seems within the range of plausible OS implementations.

Comment: Some versions of getopt() re-order the arguments by writing to argv[] (see Linux getopt).