# Is argv[n] writable?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

C11 5.1.2.2.1/2 says:

> The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall
>   be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
>   startup and program termination.

My interpretation of this is that it specifies:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if ( argv[0][0] )
        argv[0][0] = 'x';   // OK

    char *q;
    argv = &q;              // OK
}
```

however it does not say anything about:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[20];
    argv[0] = buf;
}
```

Is `argv[0] = buf;` permitted?

I can see (at least) two possible arguments:

- The above quote deliberately mentioned `argv` and `argv[x][y]` but not `argv[x]`, so the intent was that it is not modifiable
- `argv` is a pointer to non-`const` objects, so by in the absence of specific wording to the contrary, we should assume they are modifiable objects.

Comment: Related: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25126140/1505939) which asserts that `argv[n]` is non-modifiable but does not provide any justification for that assertion

Comment: When it says that `argv` can be modified I take that to mean that `argv[n]` can be. (*Of course* the `argv` pointer *itself* can be modified, it's just a function-local argument.)

Comment: @cdhowie Why do they bother to say that `argc` can be modified, that same "of course" applies to it? I think they're just talking about the local variable, not the pointers.

Comment: @cdhowie But it says "*the strings* pointed to". `argv[n]` is not a string; it's a pointer that points to the first character of a string.

Comment: @Barmar Fair point, though it seems silly to list `argc` and `argv` explicitly at all...

Comment: @MattMcNabb I am aware of that verbiage; it's also not the part I'm talking about.  Nevertheless, my interpretation is not infallible.

Comment: @cdhowie I certainly agree that it seems silly to list `argc` and `argv` explicitly , but maybe there's historical justification that I'm not aware of. Maybe it's relevant in the case of `main` being called recursively.

Comment: [Here's a legitimate reason why a particular implementation might require that `argv[n]` not be modified.](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2006-06/msg03551.html)

Comment: @hvd good point, write it as an answer perhaps. I was active on other clc threads at the same time so I should have remembered!

Comment: @MattMcNabb I posted it as a comment because it doesn't answer the question of what the standard actually requires. I don't know if the hypothetical implementation in that message would conform to the (intended) requirements of the standard.

Comment: @hvd if we accept that the standard doesn't clearly specify what it requires, then the discussion has to move onto what a likely rationale would be and what situations it's supposed to cover.

Comment: compiler doesnt treat  pointer to pointer array  `argv` nor any of pointers `argv[x]` differently from any automatic local variables or function arguments created on stack, and thus are modifiable e.g, reassignable. it makes perfectly sense, since C is meant to be powerful and efficient, and with great power comes great responsibility which is placed on programmer. C expects that you know what you are doing and it is fine that way.

Answer (score 11):

IMO, code like `argv[1] = "123";` is UB (using the original `argv`).

---

> "The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination."  C11dr & C17dr<sup>1</sup> §5.1.2.2.1 2

Recall that `const` came into C many years after C's creation.

Much like `char *s = "abc";` is valid when it should be `const char *s = "abc";`.  The need for `const` was not required else too much existing code would have be broken with the introduction of `const`.

Likewise, even if `argv` today should be considered `char * const argv[]` or some other signature with `const`, the lack of `const` in the `char *argv[]` does not completely specify the `const`-ness needs of the `argv`, `argv[]`, or `argv[][]`.  The `const`-ness needs would need to be driven by the spec.

From my reading, since the spec is silent on the issue, yet goes into depth about other assignments of `main()`'s `argv =`  and `argv[i][j] =` , it is UB.

> Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the **omission of any explicit definition of behavior**" §4 2

---

[edit]:

`main()` is a very special function in C.  What is allowable in other functions may or may not be allowed in `main()`.  The C spec details attributes about its parameters that given the signature `int argc, char *argv[]` that shouldn't need.  `main()`, unlike other functions in C, can have an alternate signature `int main(void)` and potentially others.  `main()` is not reentrant.  As the C spec goes out of its way to detail what can be modified: `argc`, `argv`, `argv[][]`, it is reasonable to question if `argv[]` is modifiable due to its omission from the spec asserting that code can.

Given the specialty of `main()` and the omission of specifying that `argv[]` as modifiable, a conservative programmer would treat this greyness as UB, pending future C spec clarification.

---

If `argv[i]` is modifiable on a given platform, certainly the range of `i` should not exceed `argc-1`.

As "`argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer", assignining `argv[argc]` to something other than `NULL` appears to be a violation.

Although the strings are modifiable, code should not exceed the original string's length.

```
char *newstr = "abc";
if (strlen(newstr) <= strlen(argv[1])) 
  strcpy(argv[1], newstr);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> No change with C17/18.  Since that version was meant to clarify many things, it re-enforces this spec is adequate and not missing an "`argv` array elements shall be modifiable".

Comment: "omission of any explicit definition of behaviour" - well, we would say `int bar = 7;` is defined despite the fact that the text "int bar = 7;" does not appear in the standard.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Normally one would readily agree with your comment's line of reasoning were it not for C11dr §5.1.2.2.1 2.  The spec goes out of the way to say some things are modifiable even though  `char *argv[]` _does not need that affirmation_.  Since the spec specifically  indicates modifiability for `argv`, and `argv[][]`, (2 out of 3) but not `argv[]`, that absence is significant - hence UB by omission. IMO, it is a weakness for the spec to imply modifiability for `argv[][]` and to be silent on `argv[]`.

Comment: @Matt McNabb A usefulness to modifiable of `argv[][]` is the direct use of `strtok()` on `argv[]` and command line arguments often need to be parsed.

Comment: I disagree (see my answer). Can you point to any actual implementation in which `argv[n]=buf` behaves badly? Or any implementation which warns against doing it?

Comment: @david.pfx  Advertising your answer here? - hmmm.  No, cannot come up with an example just like the spec does not specifically say it can be done - else OP would have seen that and there would have been no question.  We are left with a greyness in the spec and are trying to call it black or white.  In the end, until the spec is made more clear, compiler makers and C programmers will do there best.  Certainly you do not see a greyness, but if you did, how would you code: the way you think it should be or conservatively?   For me, I would code conservatively because of the possibility of UB.

Comment: In this I'm a provider rather than consumer. I would write my compiler to allow it. If I wanted to use it I would read the compiler source to find if it's safe. Sometimes for things like this there is no other way.

Comment: @david.pfx Good point on what a compiler (provider) should do!  If I  (consumer) wanted to use a dubious spec defined ability though, I would change my needs (not use it), even if the compiler I was presently using did allow it.  This avoids getting caught by compiler providers that employ [embrace, enhance, extinguish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish).

Comment: I won't labour the point, but sometimes requirements push you into places you'd rather not be, particularly if you only own/control part of the code. I've relied on worse things than this.

Comment: I came to the opposite conclusion wrt. basically the same question ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35109299/1475978)), because 1) leaving `const` out of definition of `argv` does not seem like an accidental omission to me, and 2) the standard consistently refers to `argv` as an array, and modifying an array ⇒ modifying its members, as the array itself cannot be modified as a whole; it is the adjustment done to array parameters (turning them into qualified pointers to the first element) that allows modifying `argv` itself. Is that explicit definition enough? I think so, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Nominal Animal Note: `int main(argc, argv)` as `int argc` and `char *argv[]` had lots of history before `const` was invented.

Comment: Quite true, chux. Like I mentioned in that other question, there is quite a lot of code (in olden Unix-land, and in GNU land) that expects both the pointers in the `argv` array as well as the contents of the pointed-to strings to be modifiable. I see the standard as *implying* the pointers are modifiable, and that the omission of an unambiguous explicit statement (in C99 5.1.2.2.1p2) declaring it so, is just an oversight. On the other hand, I cannot see any fault in your answer here either; I just cannot help but draw different conclusions.

Comment: @Nominal Animal Suggest adding your answer here along with your additional insights.

Answer (score 7):

The `argv` array is not *required to be* modifiable (but may be in actual implementations). This is an intentional wording which was reaffirmed in the n849 meeting in 1998:

https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n849.htm

```
PUBLIC REVIEW COMMENT #7

[...]

Comment 10.
Category: Request for information/clarification
Committee Draft subsection: 5.1.2.2.1
Title: argc/argv modifiability, part 2
Detailed description:

Is the array of pointers to char pointed to by argv modifiable?

Response Code: Q
    This is currently implictly unspecified and the committee 
    has chosen to leave it that way.
```

In addition, two separate proposals were made to, respectively, change and augment the wording. Both were rejected. Interested readers can find them by searching for "argv".

---

**Trivia:** an example in the Kernighan and Ritchie *The C Programming Language*, 2nd ed, ("K&R2") runs afoul of this. It is on page 117, and the relevant line of code is:

```
while (c = *++argv[0])
```

which increments the pointer inside the argument vector itself to step through the characters of the string.

Comment: @Kaz, thank-you for posting the informative link.  It is telling that the the requests were rejected, yet I do not see this as clearly supporting "argv array is not required to be modifiable" only that the ambiguity remains, possibly dependent on the spec as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason for this wording and restricting modifications of the `argv` array itself is to allow an implementation to allocate the `argv` array and the C strings it contains with `malloc` and free them after returning from `main`. eg:

```
    // C startup
    [...]
    // allocate the command line argument array
    int argc = os_get_argument_count();
    char **argv = malloc(sizeof *argv * (argc + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        argv[i] = strdup(os_get_argument(i));
    argv[argc] = NULL;
    [...]
    // calling main
    int status = main(argc, argv, envp);
    // call atexit functions, etc.
    [...]
    // release arguments
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        free(argv[i]);
    free(argv);
    os_exit_with_status(status);
```

If the `argv` array is modified, the above hypothetical library code would have undefined behavior.

This is a theoretical example, in practice there would be no reason for the C runtime to care about the `argv` array contents after the call to `main`, and implementations that do would fail to compile and run many C programs that modify the `argv` array for argument parsing.

Comment: Was this: `argv[0] = strdup(os_get_argument(i));` intended to be this: `argv[i] = strdup(os_get_argument(i));`? In this model changing `argv[0]` would lead to UB when attempting to free, but swapping the other pointers (as in the [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77631566/sorting-words-from-argv-by-length) that brought this up) would be ok, wouldn't it?

Comment: @adabsurdum: good catch! typo fixed. Yes, swapping the pointers would be OK for this theoretical case, but if `argv[1]` is the only one allocated and the following ones are just pointers to the same allocated area split as if by `strtok()`, swapping `argv[0]` with subsequent pointer would lead to UB :)

Comment: This seems like a plausible example. It would be nice if the Standard were more explicit on this, but what would we do if the Standard was always crystal clear?

Comment: "... allow an implementation to allocate the argv array ..." interesting rational.

Answer (score -1):

`argc` is just an `int` and is modifiable without any restriction.

`argv` is a modifiable `char **`. It means that `argv[i] = x` is valid. But it does not say anything about `argv[i]` being itself modifiable. So `argv[i][j] = c` leads to undefined behaviour.

The `getopt` function of C standard library does modify argc and argv but never modifies the actual char arrays.

Comment: Saying "`x` is modifiable" means that you are allowed to change `x`; you seem to be interpreting it as meaning "you are allowed to change what `x` points to , if x is a pointer, or if x is not a pointer than you are allowed to change x"

Comment: As quoted in the question, “the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program”, and `argv[i][j]` is part of a string pointed to by `argv`, so it is modifiable by the program.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is that argv is an array and yes, its contents are modifiable.

The key is earlier in the same section:

> If the value of argc is greater than zero, the **array** members argv[0] through
>   argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>   implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup.

From this it is clear that argv is to be thought of as an array of a specific length (argc). Then *argv is a pointer to that array, having decayed to a pointer.

Read in this context, the statement to the effect that 'argv shall be modifiable...and retain its contents' clearly intends that the contents of that array be modifiable.

I concede that there remains some ambiguity in the wording, particularly as to what might happen if argc is modified.

---

Just to be clear, what I'm saying is that I read this language as meaning:

> [the contents of the] argv [array] and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable...

So both the pointers in the array and the strings they point to are in read-write memory, no harm is done by changing them, and both preserve their values for the life of the program. I would expect that this behaviour is to be found in all the major C/C++ runtime library implementations, without exception. This is not UB.

The ambiguity is the mention of argc. It is hard to imagine any purpose or any implementation in which the value of argc (which appears to be simply a local function parameter) could not be changed, so why mention it? The standard clearly states that a function can change the value of its parameters, so why treat argc specially in this respect? It is this unexpected mention of argc that has triggered this concern about argv, which would otherwise pass without remark. Delete argc from the sentence and the ambiguity disappears.

Comment: `argv` is a pointer which points to the first element of an array, that's what `char **argv` or `char *argv[]` means in a parameter list. `argv[0]` is a member of that array, but `argv` itself isn't.   In any case , the relevant text is "the strings pointed to by the argv array", so it doesn't matter whether or not argv is called an array; as the thing being defined is *the strings pointed to*, not the array.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I still read "the argv [array] ... shall be modifiable" regardless of how you slice and dice it. Seems pretty obvious to me, hard to see why anyone would disagree.

Comment: I don't see your justification for ignoring "the strings pointed to by". another example of the same language construct: "the man shot by the policeman died". Would you say the policeman died?

Comment: I see no ambiguity in the wording, though it's possible the wording doesn't match the intent. `argv` is a pointer, not an array, and is that pointer object that the standard says is modifiable. The phrase "the `argv` array" can only refer to the array to whose first element `argv` points. The standard doesn't say whether that array is modifiable. That does seem like an odd omission, and I suspect it was not deliberate.

Comment: But it's not plausible that the standard would be so sloppy as to use the unqualified `argv` (the name of a pointer object) to refer to an array object -- *especially* when it uses the more precise and correct phrase "the `argv` array" in the same sentence. The meaning of "The parameters `argc` and `argv` ... shall be modifiable ..." is clear, and it doesn't refer to the array.

Comment: "why treat argc specially in this respect?" is because `argc` and `argv` are the parameters of `main()`.  `main()` itself in a special function detailed in the spec.  IMO, the peculiarities of the starting point for code necessitated these details for `main()`, its parameters, return value, ability to be recursively called.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I'm not sure why you say "It's not plausible that the standard would be so sloppy as to..." when there's a lot of sloppiness in the Standard.  It was written in a very different era from today, before language lawyers took over everything.

Comment: compiler doesnt treat nor pointer to pointer array  `argv` nor any of pointers `argv[x]` differently from any automatic local variables or function arguments, and thus are modifiable e.g, reassignable. it makes perfectly sense, since C is meant to be powerful and efficient, and with great power comes great responsibility.

Answer (score -2):

### It is modifiable, and `gdb` with `-std=11` shows what happens

> ISO C11, the 2011 revision of the ISO C standard. This standard is substantially completely supported’. So, let us safely assume that the gcc compiler supports most of the features proposed by the C11 standard documentation. The option –std=c11 of gcc will compile programs in C11 standard.

`argv[]` is just array of string pointers
like arguments of any other function  they  are
treated as local variables and are modifiable.
Since they belong to main() function they will last until program
exits..

`char **argv` (pointer to pointer) and `int argc` are arguments to `main()` function and thus created on a stack.

If we run this code and stop at breakpoint at main():
`:~/proba$ gdb --args proba BBBBBBB CCCCCCC`

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[20] = "AAAAAAA";
    argv[0] = buf;
    return 1;
}
```

---

```
Starting program: /home/drazen/proba/proba BBBBBBB CCCCCCC
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdef8) at main9.c:5
```

If we dump stack we see:

```
(gdb) x/32gx $sp
0x7fffffffddb0: 0x00007fffffffdef8  0x0000000300000000
0x7fffffffddc0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffddd0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
.......
```

We recognize value of `argv` `0x00007fffffffdef8`
and value of `argc` `0x00000003` on top of a stack.

Since we passed one argument `argc` is 3 as expected.

But `argv` holds address of the array of char pointers.
So at address `0x00007fffffffdef8` is actually address of the first pointer `argv[0]` with value `0x00007fffffffe25c`,
what should be an address where program name with absolute path is.

And at address `0x7fffffffdf00` is second pointer `argv[1]` with value `0x00007fffffffe275` what should be an address where first program argument is.
And at address `0x7fffffffdf08` is third pointer `argv[2]` with value `0x00007fffffffe27d` what should be an address where second program argument is.

We can see that at the stack:

```
........
0x7fffffffdef0: 0x0000000000000003            0x00007fffffffe25c<argv[0]>
0x7fffffffdf00: 0x00007fffffffe275<argv[1]>   0x00007fffffffe27d<argv[2]>
```

So `argv[0]` holds the address of program name:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x00007fffffffe25c
0x7fffffffe264: "/home/drazen/proba/proba"
```

And at address `0x00007fffffffe275` is second argument `argv[1]` which holds address of a program argument `BBBBBBB`:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x00007fffffffe275
0x7fffffffe27d: "BBBBBBB"
```

And at address `0x00007fffffffe27d` is third argument `argv[2]` which holds address of a program argument `CCCCCCC`:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x00007fffffffe27d
0x7fffffffe27d: "CCCCCCC"
```

We see that string literals these `char *argv[]` pointers points to are at consecutive addresses:

```
(gdb) x/3s 0x00007fffffffe25c
0x7fffffffe25c: "/home/drazen/proba/proba"
0x7fffffffe275: "BBBBBBB"
0x7fffffffe27d: "CCCCCCC"
```

---

Now let's step few instructions where we initialize local string
variable on stack and reassign pointer`argv[0]`:

```
(gdb) s
6       char buf[20] = "AAAAAAA";
(gdb) s
7       argv[0] = buf;
(gdb) s
8       return 1;
```

If we dump the stack now we notice it has slightly changed.
We see that local variable `buf[]` was initialized on stack too (string `AAAAAAA` is HEX `0x0041414141414141`) right after
`main()` function arguments:

```
(gdb) x/32gx $sp
0x7fffffffddb0: 0x00007fffffffdef8  0x0000000300000000
0x7fffffffddc0: 0x0041414141414141  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffddd0: 0x0000000000000000  0x5315d27018aa8e00
.....
.....
0x7fffffffdef0: 0x0000000000000003  0x00007fffffffddc0<argv[0]>
0x7fffffffdf00: 0x00007fffffffe275  0x00007fffffffe27d
```

Value `0x00007fffffffdef8` of `argv` hasn't changed, but value of `argv[0]` has changed to `0x00007fffffffddc0`:

```
.....
0x7fffffffdef0: 0x0000000000000003  0x00007fffffffddc0<argv[0]>
0x7fffffffdf00: 0x00007fffffffe275  0x00007fffffffe27d


(gdb) x/s 0x00007fffffffddc0
0x7fffffffddc0: "AAAAAAA"
(gdb) p argv[0]
$1 = 0x7fffffffddc0 "AAAAAAA"
```

pointer `argv[0]` now points to the new memory location where string literal "AAAAAAA" is allocated on a stack.

Comment: The question is about what the language standard guarantees, not about how any particular compiler behaves in some scenario

Comment: I tested scenario in question. Yes I know different compilers may work differently, but I didn't use any compiler but  gcc with `-std=11` so I my intention was to show what happens in real life with compiler which comply with the standard.