# Finding pointer to argv[0] so I can change it

Tags: c, linux, pointers, argv

On Solaris I got a pointer to `argv[0]` with `getexecname` and then I can `memcpy` at that location. (per [Finding current executable's path without /proc/self/exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe/1024937#1024937))

I was wondering how to get a pointer to `argv[0]` in Linux I did `readlink` on `/proc/self/exe` but it doesn't give me a pointer to it.

THanks

Answer (score 1):

`&argv[0]` gets you a pointer to `argv[0]`.

You can overwrite the characters stored in the array that `argv[0]` is pointing at, so long as you don't go past the existing null terminator; however it [might cause UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25737434/is-argvn-writable) to try and modify the pointer `argv[0]`.

Comment: Thanks Matt! But I don't have access to argv, Im running code from ctypes. :(

Answer (score 1):

For `readlink`, Bring Your Own Buffer. You allocate a buffer, pass in a pointer to it, and `readlink` will store the results there:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>

int main() {
  char buffer[PATH_MAX];

  int size = readlink("/proc/self/exe", buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  buffer[size] = '\0';

  // buffer is now the char* holding the filename

  printf("The executable is %s\n", buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks other guy! So after I do readlink, i can maniuplate that buffer, and that will make the change on the application?

Comment: @Noitidart No, readlink on `/proc/self/exe` is if you want to find the path to the executable. The buffer is yours and has no effect on anything else. If your question is "how do I change the executable name `top` shows for a running Python process", please ask about that instead.

Comment: Thanks other guy ill post that right now. edit: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/29159130/get-pointer-to-argv0-so-i-can-change-it