# Is it possible to add an argument to main by scanf?

Tags: c

I tried to add an argument to main by scanf. But it didn't work. The following is my program. My question is: what's wrong with this program? And is it possible to add an argument to main by scanf() instead of in the command line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    /*check if there is no argument, that is, argc!=2*/
    if(argc != 2){

        puts("Please enter an argument: ");
        scanf("%s", &argv[1]);

        printf("\nYou've entered argument: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nYou've entered argument: %s\n", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot do that.  Normal validation practice is that if arguments are missing, print out a "usage" message with parameter definitions and exit.

Comment: You need to use local variables, you cannot write `argv[1]` if  `argc < 2`

Comment: Separate issue: when using scanf for strings, you don't need the & if you are passing in the address of a string.

Comment: @samgak in this code `argv[1]` is a `char *`, not a string

Comment: If you've got a suitable POSIX-2008 compliant version of `scanf()`, you could use `scanf("%ms", &argv[1])`; otherwise, the `&argv[1]` is incorrect. You probably should not try to read an argument if the user supplied more than two arguments. You could allocate memory and pass that to `scanf()` and then set `argv[1]` to point to that memory -- it'll even be safe as long as `argc` is at least one (which it normally is) as `argv[argc]` exists and contains a null pointer. However, your argument list would no longer be terminated by a null pointer; beware code that expects it to be.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Sure. I didn't mean the C++ string type though, since this is C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is it possible to detect in the code whether `%ms` is available?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: not really.  I guess you could try: `char *pointer = 0; if (sscanf("abcdef", "%ms", &pointer) == 1 && pointer != 0) { free(pointer); ...use %ms with a modest degree of confidence... } else { ...assume %ms is not available... }`. But that's treading on thin ice!  Very thin ice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "You could allocate memory ... and then set argv[1] to point to that memory" but you'd be shot on sight for doing it, surely?

Comment: @jarmod: not necessarily.  As long as you don't go outside the range of the allocated array, you can modify `argv`.  You need to be very aware of what you're doing.  It, too, is thinnish ice; there are ways of shooting yourself in the foot, and that breaks the thin ice you're standing on. But if you are careful, you are not treading out of bounds. (You probably couldn't safely use `getopt()` on the modified array if you overwrote `argv[argc]` with a non-null pointer, for example -- it might look for a null terminating pointer, though it is told the length of the array so it might be OK, just!)

Comment: Also, if `argc == 0` then `argv[1]` causes UB. so the test `argc != 2` needs to have at least `argc != 0` included

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was hoping there might be a macro available that specifies whether the feature is available or if the library is a certain version

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Maybe `_POSIX_VERSION`?  Otherwise, no.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If you think `scanf("%ms", &argv[1])` is OK, you may to answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359

Comment: @chux it seems pretty inconclusive.. I'd hazard a guess that the standard writers don't know either but don't want to clarify it because there might already be both code out there that writes argv[n] and compilers that assume it's not writable

Comment: @Matt McNabb  Agreed.  I further see little need for messing with `argc, argv`.  Recommend posting your thoughts as a wiki answer to [Is argv n  writable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359) - maybe on its anniversary?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, code can effectively add arguments.

> "The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination." C11dr §5.1.2.2.1 2

So this allows code to change `argc` and `argv` and change `argv[0][0]` (if `argc > 0`) - but wait, there's more...

Can code change the *original* elements of `argv[]`, like `argv[1]`, etc?  That is an open question still hanging in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359).  So let us avoid that.

The way to change the contents of `argv[]` is to first create an alternate set `argv_alt[]` array and then assign `argv_alt --> argv`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Assume argc == 1
    printf("%d '%s'\n", argc, argv[0]);
    char a[3][10] = { "abc", "def", "fgh" };
    char *argv_alt[] = { a[0], a[1], a[2], NULL };
    argc = 3;
    argv = argv_alt;
    printf("%d '%s' '%s' '%s'\n", argc, argv[0], argv[1], argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` specifier in scanf expects that you pass in a pointer which points to space that has already been allocated and is big enough to hold whatever will be read.

Instead you pass in a pointer which points to an area where another pointer is stored.  This causes undefined behaviour because the pointer you pass in has the wrong type.

It's not possible to extend the length of the `argv` array. In fact, [writing to argv[n] probably causes undefined behaviour anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25737434/is-argvn-writable).

Instead you should just read into a variable inside `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Argv is allocated by the system when the user types in her arguments. If there wasn't arguments you cannot use the position 1 on that array. Although, as pointed out on the comments, you shouldn't do the way you are willing to, you could scanf arguments if you declare your own local variable.