# If argc is 1, can I still use argv[1], argv[2],... character arrays?

Tags: c, command-line, argv, argc

If there is no argument passed from the command line ie. if `argc` is `1,` can we still allocate memory for `argv[1],argv[2],.....` and use those buffers for further experiments.
If that is undefined behavior, can I still use it somehow?

Comment: If `argc` is `1` then accessing `argv[1]` or higher is probably UB.

Comment: @JoachimSauer If that leads to UB, can I somehow use it? workaround?

Comment: @JoachimSauer If `argc` is `1` then `argv[1]` will be accessible, but it will contain a null pointer.

Comment: @IanAbbott what about {argv[2], argv[3],...} Is it the same case? can we use it?

Comment: `argv[argc] == NULL` (not 100% sure that is C standard, it might also be just POSIX or implementation specific). Accessing `argv[argc+1]` or beyond is definitely Undefined Behavior. You may modify pointers in valid range of `argv`, and it is actually somewhat common practice (to hide command line arguments which are already handled, keeping unhandled ones available for other code).

Comment: @IanAbbott: fair, my C days are long ago. I think what I said still applies to `argv[2]` and up though.

Comment: Can you drive a car that doesn't exist?

Comment: @hyde `argv[argc]` is required by the C Standard to be `NULL`.  [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function)

Comment: It is more like if your cars is announced to have 2 seats, can you use seat #3 and up? No, you cannot, and you cannot "make" more seats, as the car is immutable.

Comment: @thebusybee Fair enough :)

Comment: It is also possible for `argc` to be `0`, in which case `argv[0]` will be `NULL`.

Comment: See also [Is it possible to add an argument to main by scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30904917/2410359).

Comment: One way is to re-assign `argv` to a new array of `char *`.

Answer (score 3):

No, the C standard does not specify that `argv` has any elements beyond `argv[argc]`, so they may not exist in C’s object-memory model and the behavior of using them is not defined by the C standard.

C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 2 says:

> …
>
> `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
>
> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup.
>
> …

That is all there is that defines the extent of the `argv` array; nothing in the standard says there are more elements.

When `argc` is one, using `argv[1]` is defined but using `argv[2]` is not.

You can store new values to the defined elements because C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 2 also says:

> The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

Answer (score 1):

> can I access `argv[]` elements after `argv[argc]`?

You can ... but **ONLY IN THIS CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        char *foo[] = {"bar", "baz", "quux", NULL, "bingo"};
        main(3, foo);
    } else {
        printf("argc is %d; argv[4] is \"%s\"\n", argc, argv[4]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See [code running on ideone](https://ideone.com/kvTpP9).

**In all other codes, you cannot.**

Comment: Interesting !!.

Comment: That only works if the original `argc` satisfies `argc == 1 || argc > 4`.

Comment: Yeah, snippet can be made more robust @IanAbbott :)

Comment: @pmg So if I have to use dynamic memory allocation instead of this static allocation. I need to free the character buffers...hence this won't work

Comment: Keep it simple @SauravRai, don't try and abuse `argc` and `argv`.

Comment: but you are recursively calling main() twice, so there will be two different sets of local argv[] arguments on two stack frames

Answer (score 0):

Always `argv[argc]` is equal to `NULL`. In the described case where `argc` is equal to `1` the array `argv` contains two pointers `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` where `argv[1]` is a null pointer.

You may reassign the pointers but this does not make a great sense because that will make your program unclear. Instead you could declare your own array if you need.

Comment: "You may reassign the pointers" --> [Is `argv[n]` writable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica argv is not an array of constant pointers. So the elements of the array may be reassigned.

Comment: C spec treats `main()` special.  Also, lack of `const` does not mean changing is OK. E.g. `char *s = "abc";`.  IAC, that old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359) digs into the matter and your insight is appreciated there.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Elements of the array are pointers. So to write for example argv[1] = "abc";  is a valid code. main is special in the meaning of how the array argv is initialized and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

### We probably can't allocate those data because it is already used

I didn't dive into standard to see what theory says, I suppose
behavior is undefined.
But I am more interested how real life behaves.

Let's try `gcc` complying with C18 standard  `-std=c18`on Linux OS.

Using `argv[x]` it is just a way of de-referencing `*(argv+x)`

Since`argv` is a pointer to array of char pointers
and `char *argv[]` array is also located on stack.
Since there is no arguments there is just `argv[0] = <Program Name>` and `argv[1] = <NULL>` allocated on stack.

Trying to access `argv[x]` if x > 1, you would only access some data on stack which comes after `argv[1]`.
Program stores return addresses, program arguments, local variables, and we can't be sure what data and type it may be.
So we cant just access this memory and use for our purpose.

We can try to see what happens in program compiled `gcc`
If you run this small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printf("argc is 0%d\n", argc);
   for ( int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d] is 0%s\n", i, argv[i]);
   } 
   return 1;
}
```

And you see that after `argv[0]` which points to program name, and `argv[1] = NULL`, which is delimiter, we will access some char pointers which represents environment variables which
`execve()` syscall passes to a program when it starts it:

```
drazen@HP-ProBook-640G1:~/proba$ ./proba
argc is 01
argv[0] is: ./proba
argv[1] is: (null)
argv[2] is: SHELL=/bin/bash
argv[3] is: SESSION_MANAGER=local/HP-ProBook-640G1:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1133,unix/HP-ProBook-640G1:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1133
argv[4] is: QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
argv[5] is: COLORTERM=truecolor
argv[6] is: XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-cinnamon:/etc/xdg
argv[7] is: XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
argv[8] is: GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
argv[9] is: LANGUAGE=en_US
argv[10] is: MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.mandatory.path
argv[11] is: LC_ADDRESS=hr_HR.UTF-8
argv[12] is: LC_NAME=hr_HR.UTF-8
argv[13] is: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
argv[14] is: CINNAMON_VERSION=5.8.4
```

We see that this syscall **execve()** which is called by OS after it starts our program passes array of pointers on environment variables `envp[]` after function arguments `argv[]`, so it makes sense:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

So memory on stack where `argv[]` pointers should be is already taken by pointers to environment variables.
This is how it is on Linux architecture, I didn't tested it on other systems. But I suppose on other systems, system passes some data on a stack too.

Comment: This only applies to your particular implementation.  The C standard does not specify where the `argv` array is located, it does not specify where the values of the `argv` array point to, and it doesn't specify a stack.

Comment: OK it depends on compiler. but I show how it works on GCC and Linux world, which is commonly used. and -std=c11 flag is supposedly should mean that GCC will comply with standard. and I cant see where else array of  main() function arguments would be but on a stack.