# Copy argv to another variable to change it without change the original

Tags: c, argv, execv

My program has a variable number of args and I need to make an `execv` with a new path, so I want to change the value of `argv[1]` in a different variable without changing it, but it won't let me.

```
char** arg_exec = malloc(argc * sizeof (char*));
int i;
for(i=0;i <= argc-1; i++)
   arg_exec[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
arg_exec[argc] = NULL;
if( (pid = fork()) == 0){
    arg_exec[1] = strcat(directory , dir_info->d_name); //some variables with the current path and a name
    execv(arg_exec[0], arg_exec);
    printf("Error in process %d\n", getpid());
    return 1;
 }
```

but after it runs this line `arg_exec[1] = strcat(directory , dir_info->d_name);` it changes my value of argv[1], and my program fails..

It worked fine with `execl`, since it was like `execl(argv[0],strcat(directory , dir_info->d_name), ..., NULL);` but because I have a variable number of arguments to run it, it wouldn't be good to implement that way.

Edit1: Added `NULL` at the end of the array
Edit2: I'm doing a version of the `find`, so strcat will add to the current directory a folder to look into.
This is the initalization of the directory:
`char *directory = strcat(argv[1],"/");`

Comment: What exactly is the idea behind this: `arg_exec[1] = strcat(directory , dir_info->d_name);`? And how is `directory` defined and iniatlised?

Comment: I'm doing a version of the `find`, so strcat will add to the current directory a folder to look into

Comment: Referring "*Edit1*": You missed to adjust the number of array elements to be allocated.

Comment: Note: `for(i=0;i < argc; i++)` is clearer than `for(i=0;i <= argc-1; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *directory = strcat(argv[1],"/");` attemps to modify `argv[1]` beyond its allocation, which is UB.  [@alk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43282021/2410359).

Modifying `argv` itself may be UB.  [Is argv[n] writable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359)

So allocate memory for both.

Note: `char** arg_exec = malloc(argc * sizeof (char*));` is insufficient as `argv[argc]` must be `NULL`.  Need 1 more.  Notice `argc` is not passed to `execv()`.

---

Step 1. Make a copy of the pointer array `argv[]`

```
char **argv_new;
size_t a_size = sizeof *argv_new * (argc + 1);  // + 1 for the final NULL
argv_new = malloc(a_size);
memcpy(argv_new, argv, a_size);
```

Step 2. Form the new arg[1]

```
int size = 1 + snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s/%s", argv[1], dir_info->d_name);
argv_new[1] = malloc(size);
snprintf(argv_new[1], size, "%s/%s", argv[1], dir_info->d_name);
```

Use it

```
execv(arg_new[0], arg_new);
free(argv_new[1]);
free(argv_new);
```

TBD: Error checking to add for: `argc > 1, malloc(), snprintf(), execv()`

Comment: Those calls to `free()` in the best case will never be executed ... ;-) I'd add a `perror()` before them.

Comment: @alk Maybe  
modifying `argv` is UB, maybe not.  Ref added.  Re; `perror()`, OP has `printf("Error in process %d\n", getpid());`

Answer (score 2):

The code as shown misses to `NULL`-terminate the target pointer array `arg_exec`.

To do so allocate one more element then needed and explicitly set it to `NULL`.

---

Also the second assignment the code does to `arg_exe`'s elements overwrites the result of the first, causing a memory leak, as the address to the memory allocate by `strdup()` is lost.

---

Assuming `argv` gets passed in via `main()`, then this line

```
char *directory = strcat(argv[1],"/");
```

tries to concatenate `"/"` to what `argv[1]` is pointing to and with this writes beyond the bounds of `argv[1]` and by doing so invokes undefined behaviour. From then on anything can happen, from crash to seeming to work.

BTW; please note that `directory` is just a *pointer* to `char`, so it does not provide any memory to store any "string"-like values.

What you probably want instead of

```
char *directory = strcat(argv[1],"/");

...

  arg_exec[1] = strcat(directory , dir_info->d_name);
```

is something like this (this assumes `argv[1]` holds any "base"-directorie's name and `argv_exe` is allocated and initialised as per your (corrected) code):

```
{
  void * tmp = realloc(arg_exec[1], 
    strlen(arg_exec[1]) + strlen("/") + strlen(dir_info->d_name) + 1);
  if (NULL == tmp)
  {
    perror("realloc() failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  arg_exec[1] = tmp;
}

strcat(arg_exec[1], "/");
strcat(arg_exec[1], dir_info->d_name);
```

Comment: I don't know why, but i was always getting an error with realloc. Another answer solved my problem, anyway appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You do not show how `directory` is set. I suspect that it's something like

```
char *directory = argv[1];
```

In that case, strcat will modify the location `directory` is pointing to and hence argv.

Comment: Yes, that was a problem too. Corrected it