# Sorting words from argv by length

Tags: c, string, sorting, command-line-arguments

I'm attempting to read words from the command line using `argv` in C and then sort them in descending order based on their lengths. However, my sorting algorithm is producing unexpected output.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < argc - i - 1; j++) {
            if (strlen(argv[j]) < strlen(argv[j + 1])) {
                char temp_word[20];
                strcpy(temp_word, argv[j]);
                strcpy(argv[j], argv[j + 1]);
                strcpy(argv[j + 1], temp_word);
            }
        }
    }

    puts("\n");
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc test.c -o test
./test I put this words


puwordI wordI I  %
```

Unfortunately, the output is corrupted. I suspect there might be an issue with my sorting logic or how I'm handling the command line arguments. Could someone please review my code and provide guidance on how to correctly sort the words by length?

Comment: You should not modify the strings in `argv`. Instead sort using the *pointers* (i.e. swap the pointers instead of the strings).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- Swapping pointers is a better idea, but 5.1.2.2.1 2 says that _"The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program,...."_

Comment: @adabsurdum I am sure that doesn't include exceeding their original length (as ever).

Comment: I'd recommend using `qsort` for this.

Comment: @adabsurdum @Weather Vane  Consider [Is `argv[n]` writable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, you are trying to swap the *content* of the strings in the `argv` array: this won't work, because the buffer assigned the *shorter* of two strings to be swapped will not be large enough to hold the 'replacement' from the *longer*, and will lead to undefined behaviour because of buffer overrun. Instead, just swap the actual pointers.

Second, you are not testing the whole array; take out the `- 1` from the limits in the two `for` loops.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) { // Use "argc" (not argc - 1)
        for (int j = 1; j < argc - i; j++) { // Similarly, no -1 here!
            if (strlen(argv[j]) < strlen(argv[j + 1])) {
                char* temp_word = argv[j];
                argv[j] = argv[j + 1];    // Just swap the pointers,
                argv[j + 1] = temp_word;  // not the string contents
            }
        }
    }

    puts("\n");
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: In the light of the comments about whether or not modifying the `argv` elements (as in the above code) is safe (or if it can cause undefined behaviour), I offer a version, below, that first makes a *copy* of the array, then works with that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // First, make a copy of the argv array ...
    char** argvCopy = malloc((size_t)argc * sizeof(char*));
    memcpy(argvCopy, argv, (size_t)argc * sizeof(char*));
    // Now sort that copy ...
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < argc - i; j++) {
            if (strlen(argvCopy[j]) < strlen(argvCopy[j + 1])) {
                char* temp_word;
                temp_word = argvCopy[j];
                argvCopy[j] = argvCopy[j + 1];
                argvCopy[j + 1] = temp_word;
            }
        }
    }

    puts("\n");
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s ", argvCopy[i]);
    }

    free(argvCopy); // Don't forget to free the copy.
    return 0;
}
```

Refer also to the discussions here: [Is argv[n] writable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/10871073)

Comment: `argv[j] = ...` is a reasonable approach, yet is it UB?  Many attributes about `main()` are special.  Old question [Is `argv[n]` writable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359) is still open and would benefit with any additional insight you may have.

Comment: @chux I can't see why it would (or could) be UB. We're just swapping pointers. Now, if we were to (say) add extra pointers to the end of the `argv[]` array (and accordingly increase `argc`), then *that* may provoke UB.

Comment: It simply _could_ because of that discussion [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359).

Comment: @chux OK - see edit! :)

Comment: Re: "Is argv[n] writable?" --> It is a regrettable ill specified corner of C as IMO, spec should be altered to clearly allow a writable `argv[n]`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I fully agree with your remark. Definitely regrettable.

Answer (score 3):

Re-writing the *strings* stored at `argv[i]` is a problem if a longer string is attempted to be stored in a place of a shorter one.

Further, as writing `argv[i]` may be [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359) we could use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *argv_copy[argc];  // VLA or use malloc
  memcpy(argv_copy, argv, sizeof argv_copy);

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < argc - 1; j++) {
      if (strlen(argv_copy[j]) < strlen(argv_copy[j + 1])) {
        // Swap pointers
        char *tmp_ptr = argv_copy[j];
        argv_copy[j] = argv_copy[j+1];
        argv_copy[j+1] = tmp_ptr;
      }
    }
  }
  const char *sep = "";
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("%s%s", sep, argv_copy[i]);
    sep = " ";
  }
  puts("");  // Write 1 \n

  return 0;
}
```

Even better code would use `qsort()`, yet may be beyond OP at this time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int fcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  size_t length_a = strlen(*((const char**) a));
  size_t length_b = strlen(*((const char**) b));
  // Compare lengths (Perhaps the other way around?)
  return (length_a > length_b) - (length_a < length_b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 0) {
    char *argv_copy[argc];  // VLA or use malloc
    memcpy(argv_copy, argv, sizeof argv_copy);
    qsort(&argv_copy[1], argc - 1, sizeof *argv_copy, fcmp);
    const char *sep = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      printf("%s%s", sep, argv_copy[i]);
      sep = " ";
    }
    puts("");  // Write 1 \n
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although not strictly necessary for this exercise, `argv_copy` should be defined with a length of `argc + 1` for consistency with the `argv` array contents.

Answer (score 2):

The C Standard defines the `main` arguments this way:

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
>
> 1   The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:
>
> `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
>
> or equivalent<sup>10)</sup>; or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> 2    If they are declared, the parameters to the `main` function shall obey the following constraints:
> — The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
> — `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
> — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` represent the program parameters.
> — The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

Thus the argument strings can be modified but if you write beyond the end of any of these strings, the behavior is undefined, which is what you experience.

You should not modify the contents of the argument strings if they do not have the same length. You should instead modify the pointers to the argument strings in `argv`.  Yet the C Standard does not specify if the `argv` array itself can be modified, so you should use a copy of the array.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *newargv[argc + 1];

    // copy the argument array
    for (int i = 0; i <= argc; i++) {
        newargv[i] = argv[i];
    }

    argv = newargv;

    // sort the argument array
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < argc - i; j++) {
            if (strlen(argv[j]) < strlen(argv[j + 1])) {
                char *temp = argv[j];
                argv[j] = argv[j + 1];
                argv[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    // print the arguments
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much)), I tried to run the program and I understood that I also need to modify
for (int j = 1; j < argc - i; j++)
now it works perfectly
gcc test.c -o test
./test I put these words
words this put I

Comment: "You should not modify the contents of the argument strings," --> Yes, due to length concerns, yet otherwise modifying string arguments is OK per "The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program ..." C17 §5.1.2.2.1 2

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: yes, you are right, and it says nothing about the array itself, so my implementation is not guaranteed to work.  I shall rephrase this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**An advanced idea for OP**

When comparing many strings, which is unlikely in OP's case given it is likely only a handful or command line arguments, it is often preferable to avoid many trips down a string to find its length.

Code below finds the string lengths once and then uses the speedy `qsort()` to sort based on the string length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  size_t len;
  char *str;
} len_str;

int fcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  const len_str *pa = a;
  const len_str *pb = b;
  return (pb->len > pa->len) - (pb->len < pa->len);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 0) {
    len_str pair[argc];  // VLA or use malloc()
    for (int a = 1; a < argc; a++) {
      pair[a].len = strlen(argv[a]);
      pair[a].str = argv[a];
    }
    qsort(pair + 1, argc - 1, sizeof *pair, fcmp);
    const char *sep = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      printf("%s%s", sep, pair[i].str);
      sep = " ";
    }
    puts("");  // Write 1 \n
  }
  return 0;
}
```